# Java POO - Pregunta Simple

Tags: java, poo

Tengo una duda muy concreta en POO, y quisiera saber por favor si me pueden ayudar con este simple código.

Es muy simple, tengo 2 clases, una llamada `Aeropuerto` (con el nombre del aeropuerto, dirección, año inauguración y capacidad) y la otra `Dirección` con el país, la calle el numero y ciudad.

También tengo la clase `TestAeropuerto`, donde desde aquí empieza todo.
Creo un objeto a1 de tipo Aeropuerto,(1er constructor) y ahí me regresa los datos con un `toString`, y entiendo el razonamiento.

El problema es cuando creo un objeto del tipo Dirección y lo tengo que relacionar con el objeto a2 de tipo Aeropuerto.

Observen mi razonamiento:

Al crear el objeto de tipo Dirección llamado México, al constructor de la clase Dirección le paso el país, calle, numero y ciudad), lo cual, el constructor le pasa esos parámetros a los atributos de la clase, y se guardan en memoria. Entendidisimo.

Ahora, cuando creo al objeto a2 de tipo Aeropuerto, llama el otro constructor de su clase, donde pasa por parámetro: nombre, dirección, anioInauguracion y cantidad. Todos se almacenan en memoria y perfecto, pero.... que para con el atributo Direccion direccion que esta en la clase Aeropuerto? Como hace para buscar los tipos de datos primitivos que estan guardados en memoria en la clase Direccion? Como recurre/obtiene el objeto Direccion direccion solito (en la clase Aeropuerto) a los atributos  país, calle, numero y ciudad de la clase Direccion? Tiene algo que ver el método toString o funciona como un getter común en este caso?

Disculpen la pregunta básica, pero necesito saber como la computadora hacer para vincular esos datos. Paso por paso
Código:

```
public class TestAeropuerto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Aeropuerto a1 = new Aeropuerto("Pistarini", "Argentina", "Arevalo", 2364, "Buenos Aires", 1976, 2000);

    System.out.println(a1);

    System.out.println(a1.aniosAbierto());

    Direccion mexico = new Direccion("Mexico", "11 de Septiembre", 2871, "Cancun");

    Aeropuerto a2 = new Aeropuerto("Las Americas", mexico, 1980, 4000);

    System.out.println(a2);

    System.out.println(a2.aniosAbierto());

}

}

class Direccion {

private String pais;
private String calle;
private int numero;
private String ciudad;

public Direccion(String pais, String calle, int numero, String ciudad) {

    this.pais = pais;
    this.calle = calle;
    this.numero = numero;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public String getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(String pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

public String getCalle() {
    return calle;
}

public void setCalle(String calle) {
    this.calle = calle;
}

public int getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(int numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getCiudad() {
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Direccion [pais=" + pais + ", calle=" + calle + ", numero=" + numero + ", ciudad=" + ciudad + "]";
}

}

class Aeropuerto {

private String nombre;
private Direccion direccion;
private int anioInauguracion;
private int capacidad;

public Aeropuerto(String nombre, String pais, String calle, int numero, String ciudad, int anioInauguracion,
        int capacidad) {

    this.direccion = new Direccion(pais, calle, numero, ciudad);
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.anioInauguracion = anioInauguracion;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
}

public Aeropuerto(String nombre, Direccion direccion, int anioInauguracion, int capacidad) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.anioInauguracion = anioInauguracion;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getAnioInauguracion() {
    return anioInauguracion;
}

public void setAnioInauguracion(int anioInauguracion) {
    this.anioInauguracion = anioInauguracion;
}

public int getcapacidad() {
    return capacidad;
}

public void setcapacidad(int capacidad) {
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
}

public int aniosAbierto() {
    int dia = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return dia - anioInauguracion;

}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Aeropuerto [nombre=" + nombre + " direccion=" + direccion + " Año Inauguracion=" + anioInauguracion
            + ", capacidad=" + capacidad + "]";
}

}
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. En tu clase Aeropuerto no estás accediendo a ningún miembro del objeto de la clase Direccion que tienes definido. _Como hace para buscar los tipos de datos primitivos que estan guardados en memoria en la clase Direccion?_ De ninguna manera porque no has escrito código para que tenga que hacer eso.

Comment: Hola Roger! Si compila el código veras que de alguna manera que no puedo entender, el atributo Direccion direccion *le pide* a los tipos primitivos de la clase Direccion los datos. El como es lo que no puedo entender.

Comment: No le pide nada a nadie. Lo que haces es llamar al constructor de la clase `Direccion`, que construye un objeto de la clase `Direccion` y  guarda una referencia en la variable `this.direccion`. En el segundo constructor, recibe el objeto ya creado fuera de la clase `Aeropuerto` y simplemente guarda la referencia al objeto, el mismo objeto al que apunta la variable `mexico`. Solo un objeto, dos referencias.

Comment: Hola! Hace 1 hora estoy analizando palabra por palabra lo último que me escribiste y se nota que realmente sabes bien del tema. Me pierdo en esta parte: "En el segundo constructor recibe el objeto ya creado fuera de la clase Aeropuerto (por ahora bien), y simplemente *guarda la referencia al objeto* (guarda: this. direcioon=dirección), es decir al mismo this.direccion? Y acá viene lo duro : *el mismo objeto al que apunta la variable mexico* Me explicaras porfa en líneas de código esa parte porfa? Sos un genio..

Comment: Acabé de ver tu vídeo. He editado mi respuesta. La razón es muy simple.

Comment: En Java todo son referencias. Esto significa que cuando haces `new` y creas un objeto, se crea en memoria una vez y ahí se queda. Y le asignas un nombre para acceder a él cuando asignas el retorno de `new` en una variable: `Direccion var = new Direccion(...)`. El objeto está en memoria y la variable`var` apunta a él. Si luego asignas el valor de `var` en otra variable `Direccion var2 = var;` no creas otro objeto. El objeto es el mismo. `var2` y `var` apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria. Si cambias algo en el objeto apuntado por `var2`, el cambio se verá reflejado en `var`. Solo hay un objeto.

Comment: Voy a anotar en mi carpeta @SuperG280 lo que me estas diciendo. Hay gente que en verdad no sabe la diferencia entre punteros y objetos, y recien ahora estoy entendiendo un poquito mas gracias a ustedes. Muchos programadores hacen todo esto de memoria, lo cual esta pesimo, y de ahi, vienen las concencuencias de codigos sin sentido, con exceso de lineas, no reutiliables, etc etc. Mil gracias!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea de código:

```java
Aeropuerto a2 = new Aeropuerto("Las Americas", mexico, 1980, 4000);
```

Crea un objeto en memoria, en la cual, cada atributo, internamente representa una dirección de memoria. Por lo tanto, después de la creación del objeto, se asigna la dirección base del objeto al [puntero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puntero_(inform%C3%A1tica)) `a2`.

La variable `a2` es simplemente un puntero implícito, en la cual, almacenará la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del objeto.

En este diagrama de memoria se visualiza mejor:

```java
Bloque A:
|0x04|           Bloque B:
|0x08| --> |0x64|0x65|0x66|0x67|
|0x0A|
|0x0B|
```

El bloque `A` representa el objeto de tipo `Aeropuerto`, donde el puntero `a2` estaría apuntando a la dirección base de dicho objeto (en este caso sería hacia la dirección `0x04`). Recalco, las direcciones de memoria que tiene el bloque `A`, simplemente son los atributos del objeto (por ejemplo, la dirección `0x08` en como si fuera el atributo `direccion`). El bloque `B` representa las direcciones de memoria de cada atributo del objeto `Direccion` (al que apunta el puntero `mexico`).

Posteriormente cuando el objeto ya está en memoria, recién se llega a ejecutar el constructor (como un método común y corriente) y ahí es donde se pasan los argumentos a cada parámetro de dicho constructor. Pero nos vamos a enfocar en el segundo parámetro que vendría ser de tipo `Direccion`. Este parámetro en realidad es un puntero en la cual almacenará la dirección base del objeto de tipo `Direccion` (es decir, la dirección `0x64`) que se había creado anteriormente, luego se pasa a ejecutar esta instrucción:

```java
this.direccion = direccion;
```

Luego nos damos cuenta que la clase `Aeropuerto` tiene otro puntero de tipo `Direccion` que se llama `direccion`, entonces este apuntador lo que almacenará es la dirección base del objeto de tipo `Direccion` al que apuntaba el parámetro `direccion` del constructor de la clase `Aeropuerto`.

Si regresamos a nuestro diagrama de memoria, nos podemos dar cuenta, que la dirección de memoria de este atributo `direccion` es `0x08` y que en este registro de memoria es donde estará almacenada la dirección base del objeto de tipo `Direccion` (es decir, la dirección `0x64)`.

La palabra `this` simplemente es un puntero en la cual tiene la dirección base del objeto actual que se haya creado. En este caso, el puntero `this` apunta hacia la misma dirección que `a2` (es decir, hacia la dirección `0x04`, debido a que, es la dirección base de dicho objeto).

Por esa razón es posible asignar el contenido del parámetro `direccion` (del constructor) hacia el atributo `direccion` (de la clase `Aeropuerto`), debido a que, a partir del puntero `this`, se le suma un [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) (calculado por el compilador) en la cual nos servirá para obtener la dirección de memoria del atributo `direccion` (que vendría ser la dirección `0x08`) y de este modo, poder asignarle la dirección `0x64` al puntero/atributo `direccion` (de la clase `Aeropuerto)` y de esta forma es como en realidad funciona esta línea de código: `this.direccion = direccion`.

Entendiendo este funcionamiento interno, podríamos responder a tus preguntas:

> > Todos se almacenan en memoria y perfecto, pero.... que para con el atributo Direccion direccion que esta en la clase Aeropuerto?

El atributo `direccion` es simplemente un puntero en la cual espera la dirección de memoria del primer atributo del objeto de tipo `Direccion`. Básicamente este apuntador lo que tendrá almacenado es la misma dirección de memoria al que apuntaba `mexico`.

> > Como recurre/obtiene el objeto Direccion direccion solito (en la clase Aeropuerto) a los atributos país, calle, numero y ciudad de la clase Direccion?

La variable `direccion` no es un objeto, sino, un puntero que apunta hacia la dirección base de un objeto.

Es decir, si tenemos el siguiente código:

```java
public Aeropuerto(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.direccion.setNumero(10);
}
```

Podríamos modificar el contenido de un atributo del objeto `Direccion`, debido a que, el puntero `direccion` (de la clase `Aeropuerto`) apunta hacia dirección base del objeto de tipo `Direccion`, por lo tanto, es válido invocar el método `setNumero` de la clase `Direccion`. Si nunca hubiéramos realizado esta asignación:

```java
this.direccion = direccion;
```

Nos hubiera dado una excepción `NullPointerException`, debido a que, el atributo/puntero/variable `direccion` se quedaría apuntando a `null`.

Por último, si ejecutamos este código:

```java
Direccion mexico = new Direccion("Mexico", "11 de Septiembre", 2871, "Cancun");
System.out.println(mexico);
```

Nos saldrá como resultado:

```java
Direccion [pais= Mexico, calle= 11 Septiembre, numero= 2871, ciudad= Cancun]
```

**¿Por qué nos salió ese resultado?**

La respuesta es simple, el compilador de Java está invocando implícitamente al método `toString()` (de la clase `Direccion`). Por esa razón nos imprime ese resultado.

Esto quiere decir, que cuando escribas este código:

```java
System.out.println(mexico);
```

El compilador lo transforma a:

```java
System.out.println(mexico.toString());
```

Sin embargo, si ahora eliminamos el método `toString` de la clase `Direccion`, nos imprime el siguiente resultado:

```java
Direccion@1637f22
```

Y esto se debe porque está invocando al método `toString()` heredado de la clase `Object` (es la clase base y todas las clases heredan de ella).

Y esto lo podemos comprobar de esta manera:

```java
System.out.println(mexico.toString());
System.out.println(mexico);
```

Imprimen el mismo resultado.

Comment: Dios, hay en verdad genios en este grupo y personas que saben mucho. Sin palabras, magistral. Ojala algun dia sepa realmente de informatica como ustedes. Que mas decir que mil gracias. Un dios.

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a las propiedades de la propiedad `Direccion` que guardas con el segundo constructor solo tienes que hacer referencia a ellas como si tratases un objeto de tipo `Direccion`. Te pongo un ejemplo basado en tu código para que quede más claro.

Tu lo primero que haces es instanciar un nuevo objeto de tipo `Direccion`, hasta aqui por lo que has dicho todo correcto.

```
Direccion mexico = new Direccion("Mexico", "11 de Septiembre", 2871, "Cancun");
```

Si quisieses acceder a cualquiera de las propiedades de este objeto `mexico` de tipo `Direccion`, lo harías de la siguiente manera:

```
mexico.getPais();
mexico.getCalle();
mexico.toString();
...
```

Hasta aquí, por lo que comentas todo controlado. Pues lo único que tienes que hacer es replicar esto con el objeto `Aeropuerto`

```
//Instancias el aeropuerto
Aeropuerto a2 = new Aeropuerto("Las Americas", mexico, 1980, 4000);

//Obtenemos la direccion
Direccion dirA2 = a2.getDireccion();

//Recuperamos la propiedad que queramos
dirA2.getPais();
dirA2.getCalle();
dirA2.toString();
...
```

Y si lo quieres mostrar por consola, tan facil como

```
System.out.println(dirA2.toString());
//O más directo
System.out.println(a2.getDireccion().toString());
```

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Hola Miguel, en tu ejemplo esta muy claro! Pero basado en mi código, como hace ese objeto a2 (que viaja hacia la clase Aeropuerto, luego se almacena en el atributo Direccion dirección, para "reencontrarse" con los atributos de tipo primitivos que están en la clase Direccion? Capaz mi pregunta es rara, pero quiero entender el camino que hace la compu!

Comment: Con los getters que ya tienes definidos en la clase Direccion. Tu ten en cuenta que al final tienes atributos que son objetos, algunos primitivos y otros más complejos. Los más complejos (Direccion) tienen sus propios atributos accesibles con los getters correspondientes.

Comment: Hola Miguel! Mira, tienes toda la razon lo que estas explicando, pero me parece que por lo menos en el codigo que escribi yo, la mano viene como esta comentando @SuperG280. Mira: No le pide nada a nadie. Lo que haces es llamar al constructor de la clase Direccion, que construye un objeto de la clase Direccion y guarda una referencia en la variable this.direccion. En el segundo constructor, recibe el objeto ya creado fuera de la clase Aeropuerto y simplemente guarda la referencia al objeto, el mismo objeto al que apunta la variable mexico. Solo un objeto, dos referencias.

Comment: Hola Miguel, aca esta mi duda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LHUyaDnExVo&t=12s

Comment: @Gonzalo El objeto no viaja. Lo que se pasa al atributo `direccion`, es simplemente la dirección base del objeto de tipo `Direccion` (al que apunta el puntero `mexico`).

Comment: Mil gracias a todos! Unos genios... sin palabras